# how to find near places with json api (with a non google-places-api service)

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, google-places-api

I am working on a android app project that tells nearby places with json api (non-google service).
I am stuck at a error that gives,

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.test2.masjid$ParserTask.onPostExecute(masjid.java:172)
        at com.example.test2.masjid$ParserTask.onPostExecute(masjid.java:151)
```

I dont know whats wrong with my code, first this is my json result

```
{
"ArrayOfmasjid": {
    "masjid": [
        {
            "Distance": {
                "_i:nil": "true"
            },
            "_id": {
                "_a": {
                    "__prefix": "d3p1",
                    "__text": "1471915691"
                },
                "_b": {
                    "__prefix": "d3p1",
                    "__text": "1140779876"
                },
                "_c": {
                    "__prefix": "d3p1",
                    "__text": "-398269374"
                },
                "_xmlns:d3p1": "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MongoDB.Bson"
            },
            "masjidAddress": {
                "city": "Bhopal",
                "country": "India",
                "description": {
                    "_i:nil": "true"
                },
                "googlePlaceId": "ChIJTRpmAyJofDkRoddd-ANr4XM",
                "locality": "Peer Gate Area",
                "phone": {
                    "_i:nil": "true"
                },
                "state": "Madhya Pradesh",
                "street": "Chowk Bazaar Rd",
                "zipcode": "462001"
            },
            "masjidCreatedby": "saud@saudkhan.net",
            "masjidCreatedon": "2016-08-23T01:28:10.789Z",
            "masjidId": "57bba6ab43feeb64e842e442",
            "masjidLocation": {
                "coordinates": {
                    "double": [
                        {
                            "__prefix": "d4p1",
                            "__text": "77.4019681"
                        },
                        {
                            "__prefix": "d4p1",
                            "__text": "23.2586956"
                        }
                    ],
                    "_xmlns:d4p1": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
                },
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "masjidModifiedby": "saud@saudkhan.net",
            "masjidModifiedon": "2016-08-23T01:28:10.789Z",
            "masjidName": "Jama Masjid",
            "masjidPic": {
                "_i:nil": "true"
            },
            "masjidTimings": {
                "asr": {
                    "_i:nil": "true"
                },
                "fajr": {
                    "_i:nil": "true"
                },
                "isha": {
                    "_i:nil": "true"
                },
                "jumah": {
                    "_i:nil": "true"
                },
                "maghrib": {
                    "_i:nil": "true"
                },
                "zuhr": {
                    "_i:nil": "true"
                }
            },
            "notMasjid": "false"
        },
```

and this is my main Activity

```
public class masjid extends FragmentActivity {

SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
GoogleMap map;
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
double currentLat = 0, currentLong = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_masjid);
    supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);

    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(masjid.this
            , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        getCurrentLocation();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(masjid.this
                , new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 44);
    }
    String url = "https://masjidnear.me/api/Masjid/SearchMasjids/query/pin$462001/";

    new PlaceTask().execute(url);

}

private void getCurrentLocation() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    }
    Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {

                currentLat = location.getLatitude();
                currentLong = location.getLongitude();

                supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                        map = googleMap;
                        LatLng Location = new LatLng(currentLat,currentLong);
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Location).title("You are here"));

                        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                new LatLng(currentLat, currentLong), 10
                        ));
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull String[] permissions, @NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 44) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        }

    }
}


private class PlaceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String data = null;
        try {
            data = downloadUrl(strings[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        new ParserTask().execute(s);
    }
}

private String downloadUrl(String string) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(string);
    HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    connection.connect();

    InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    String line = "";

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line);
    }
    String data = builder.toString();
    reader.close();
    return data;
}

private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>> {
    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... strings) {

        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        List<HashMap<String,String>> mapList = null;
        JSONObject object = null;
        try {
            object = new JSONObject(strings[0]);

            mapList= jsonParser.parseResult(object);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mapList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> hashMaps) {
        map.clear();

        for (int i=0; i<hashMaps.size();i++){
            HashMap<String,String> hashMapList = hashMaps.get(i);

            double lat = Double.parseDouble(hashMapList.get("__text"));

            double lng = Double.parseDouble(hashMapList.get("__text"));

            String name = hashMapList.get("name");

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat,lng);

            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

            options.position(latLng);

            options.title(name);

            map.addMarker(options);

        }
    }
}
```

and this is my JSON parser

```
public class JsonParser {
private HashMap<String, String> parseJsonObject(JSONObject object) {


    HashMap<String, String> datalist = new HashMap<>();

    try {
        String name = object.getString("masjidName");

        String latitude = object.getJSONObject("masjidLocation").getJSONObject("coordinates").getJSONArray("double").getJSONObject(1).getString("__text");

        String longitude = object.getJSONObject("masjidLocation").getJSONObject("coordinates").getJSONArray("double").getJSONObject(0).getString("__text");

        datalist.put("name",name);
        datalist.put("__text",latitude);
        datalist.put("__text",longitude);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return datalist;
}
private List<HashMap<String,String>> parseJsonArray(JSONArray jsonArray){

    List<HashMap<String,String>> datalist = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++){

        try {
            HashMap<String,String> data = parseJsonObject((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(1));

            datalist.add(data);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return datalist;
}
public List<HashMap<String, String>> parseResult(JSONObject object){
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

    try {
        jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("masjid");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return parseJsonArray(jsonArray);
}
```

Comment: Difficult to debug, but a couple of things. The URL you are using returns XML not JSON, and shouldn't `parseJsonObject((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(1));` being using the increment integer, not "1"?

Comment: Okay,  how to parse xml instead of json??

Comment: For that, I'd search [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)